# WPF Window Chrome styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, styles, window-chrome

I'm using [WindowChrome class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) for solving problem with different icons in task bar and app header. Here is my window.style example:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" 
                                    ResizeBorderThickness="4"  
                                    UseAeroCaptionButtons="True"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
                    <Grid>

                        <!-- This is the ContentPresenter that displays the window content. -->
                        <Border Margin="1 30 1 1" Background="White"
                                >
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </Border>

                        <!-- Window Title -->
                        <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="16" Height="16" Source="some.ico"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Margin="25 5 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Left" 

                                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                 {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

When not maximized - my window looks as I want. 
[image]

But when maximized(by double click/maximize button click or dock to the top) the header background is black, I can't see any buttons and my icon is out of the screen bounds. :(

[image]

Any suggestions? What i'm doing wrong in my style?